# How to use typeahead in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do autocomplete in which data is taken from url .I have written a code but its displaying undefined .Can anyone help me out to solve this problem

```
//html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Autocomplete using remote searching</title>

<script src="angularfiles/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="Jsfiles/autourl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controller">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <input type="text" ng-model="asyncselected" typeahead="r.city for r in getlist($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults">
        <i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
        <div ng-show="noResults">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

//Js file

var app=angular.module("myapp",['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller("controller",['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.getlist=function(val){
        return $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php").then(function(response){
            return response.data.results.map(function(item){
                return item.City;
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

May be the jsfile code is some what wrong..I am unable to identify.Can anyone help me to solve .

Comment: You can follow this, its a well explained article:
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Comment: Its lengthy to write the directive..So i have tried like above..I just have doubt at then statement...

Comment: The html of input field for your typeahead looks fine to me. 
Issue is with your getlist function. 
This is a working typeahead example. 
You can check this out : 
http://jsfiddle.net/nicktest222/JXtaZ/24/

Comment: It can be done using angucomplete-alt  right.Can anyone solve it using it..Even i have tried it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a AngularUI directive. It's a good approach and I use it.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: ya but im little bit confused in js file at getlist function..everythng is at that function .can u help me